# DAX: How to count how many months have sales in a period

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

In my fact table (fTable) the columns I have are dates, region and sales.

| dates | region | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ----- | ------ | ----- |

I am visualizing the data in a pivot table with regions as rows and months as columns (I have a date table (dDate) with a months column in my model)

I am looking for a way to dynamically change the denominator in an averaging measure if a certain region doesn't have sales in a given month. Right now my denominator is hard-coded as 6, because I am averaging 6 variables in my nominator, but any one of them could be 0 if I don't have any sales in a certain month, in which case my denominator needs to change to 5, 4 or less depending on how many months I don't have sales in. So I am looking to count how many of the past 6 months have sales and sum that as the denominator.

I have managed to count months with sales this way:

```
Denominator:=
var newTable = Summarize(fTable,fTable[date (month)], fTable[region],"Sales",[Sum of Sales])
var MonthsWithSales = Countrows(newTable)

RETURN
MonthsWithSales
```

I've tried to RETURN

```
Calculate(SUMX(newTable,MonthsWithSales), Dateadd(dDate[Date],-6,MONTH)
```

but it yields a wrong result.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Based on my sample, we can use function VALUES & COUNTROWS inside CALCULATE to get what we need:

[image]

```
Measure = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(VALUES('Table (2)'[Month])), ALL('Table (2)'[Month]) )
```

[image]

Comment: What I am looking for, using your sample, is, when filter context is in April - how many months with sales does 'A' have for the previous six months? - in this case 0. In May, how many months with sales does 'A' have for the previous six months? - one. In June, how many months with Sales does 'A' have for the previous six months? - one. Etc.